# Excel: "Dynamic" CountIfs, MinIfs, PercentileIfs

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm trying to make my spreadsheet as 'dynamic' as possible as I need to create a number of tables with different variables that influence the data in them... the variable columns will be the same for every table created, but the data within the columns may vary.

I noticed that wild cards in the cells themselves are helpful to a point. Where there's a `SUMIF`, `COUNTIF`, these are awesome for solving my problem... but if it's an embedded `IF` statement, the logical test can't equal the cell with the wildcard in without causing errors.

Ultimately I will have four data tabs and an abundance of different tables based on the variables. I would love to do this in pivot tables that would absolve me of this issue, however I can't figure out how to do percentiles in the pivots :)

[image: Current Set Up]

[image: Example Data]

[image: Headcount Formula]

[image: Min Formula without Level populated]

[image: Min Formula with Level populated (I need to change the <> to = manually]

For the Level column to calculate properly, I need to change the <> to = manually... which I am hoping to avoid if possible given the number of these I need to create

Comment: So... just to clarify... your question is "how do I replace `<>` with `=` automatically?"  Sorry, with all of this information, I wasn't 100% clear on the actual question at hand.

Comment: Yes, that's a question that an answer to would solve my problem. If a cell in the parameters is populated, change <> to = in the formula.

Another is a solution to the wildcards existing in the cells and how to run 'if' statements off of those, as I think I could use = for everything then.

Comment: The problem I have here is, it sounds like you just want to find/replace in all FORMULAS, just the `<>` with `=` in my previous comment.  However, throughout the question, it sounds like you're asking for other advice on creating formulas - **but I don't see any example formulas like you're talking about** - even though the screenshots are helpful.

Comment: If you just want to replace in FORMULAS, what happens if you highlight the whole column, do `Ctrl+F`, click `Options` and make sure `Look In` is set to FORMULAS?  Please consider an [edit] to your question to more specifically narrow down your scope, and please include an [mcve] of your formulas if you need additional help.

Comment: As an example, I need to run this for lots of countries so instead of changing the "<>" to "=" I want a smarter formula that changes based on what's populated in the 'Parameters' section.

Country, Pool, Level (and additional columns I didn't include as this is just a sample made up for the purpose of asking this question) will change based on these parameters I need tables for. Ultimately I want to make this a more automatic exercise by having the formulas be smarter or more dynamic.

Comment: In the white section where there are Levels populated, this is a different formula to the grey sections where there are no Levels populated (in the white section, D6 = D10 whereas in the grey section D6 <> D10). In the ideal state, these would be the SAME formula, with the parameters being the only thing changing as the formulas in the table are smart enough to pick up on that and only grab the right data from the data sets.

Comment: Another question: is there a way to make an IF statement run off of a wildcard in a cell? i.e. cell A1 is populated with *
Because SUMIF does and COUNTIF does but MIN(IF) doesn't. Finding a way to have an IF statement run off of a wildcard like it's SUMIF and COUNTIF counterparts do then I have a solution